# Long list of values of Ramanujan Tau function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, analytic-functions

In order to study Ramanujan tau function I need a long list of values. After some search in the internet I did not find a source that has a comprehensive list, i.e. more then 250 entries.

I would be very thankful if someone knows such a source.

Comment: Have you looked at the [oeis entry](https://oeis.org/A000594)?

Comment: Of course, since I am not really experienced with oeis correct me if I am wrong, but I can find only 28 entries...

Comment: [here](https://oeis.org/A000594/b000594.txt) for instance is a fairly long list (taken from the oeis entry).

Comment: You have to go through all their references to find a longer list.  I linked to it in my prior comment.

Comment: Indeed, now I see it, thank you

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha knows how to compute $\tau(n)$.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RamanujanTau%5BRange%5B500%5D%5D)

Comment: The command list(delta_qexp(20)) works in SAGE (CoCalc).

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* gives 10,000 values in 7.5 seconds on a Mac desktop:

```
Table[RamanujanTau[n], {n, 10000}]
```

where the first twenty entries are:

$$\{1, -24, 252, -1472, 4830, -6048, -16744, 84480, -113643,$$

$$-115920, 534612, -370944, -577738, 401856, 1217160,$$

$$987136, -6905934, 2727432, 10661420, -7109760\}$$

If you have multicores (e.g., eight), you can get $100,000$ values in $16.9$ seconds by:

```
Parallelize[Table[RamanujanTau[n], {n, 100000}]]
```

This speed is faster than $10$ times the speed on a single core, proving (given parallelization partitioning and communication overhead) that there is some true benefit to parallelization.

As far as I can tell, *Mathematica* does not compute the RamanujanTau function iteratively.  As evidence:  *Mathematica* computes the single $100000$th RamanujanTau value in 0.000168 seconds... (much less than a millisecond) perhaps NOT an iterative algorithm.

I know of no way to speed up the computation for $n =$ prime, but parallelization allows you to compute those values in parallel, e.g., for some primes on core 1, other primes on core 2, and so on.
If $n =$ prime, there is no help in iterative schemes.  Here the benefit of Parallellize in *Mathematica* is quite evident.  If we compute the RamaujanTau for the first 2000 primes, it takes $6.55$ seconds on a single core and just $0.213$ seconds on an eight-core machine.  Clearly this is done by the first 2000/8 primes on core 1, the second 2000/8 on core 2, and so forth.

Regardless, the details of *Mathematica*'s internal algorithm need not concern us--and they certainly do not concern the question poser.  All that is necessary for obtaining very large sets of values through parallelization is that the function calls can be run in parallel, as described above.  So to the question "parallelizing what?", the answer is clearly:  "parallelizing the calls to the non-iterative algorithm for computing RamanujanTau."

Any concern for *Mathematica*'s internal algorithm is completely misplaced and irrelevant to the explicit question as posed.  The OP explicitly seeks a *list* of values, and expresses no interest whatsoever in the algorithm, nor even the *speed* at which the algorithm runs.  I don't know the internal details of *Mathematica*'s algorithm, and don't care, and for this problem neither should anybody.  Everyone on this page (save one poster) understands this simple point, as is clear from their answers which link to the OEIS or LMFDB or methods for computing, such as *WolframAlpha*, as was positively acknowledged and accepted in a comment by the OP.

Comment: Parallelizing what ?

Comment: Obviously:  Parallelizing the computation of the RanaujanTau function, which means running the operations on all eight cores simultaneously.  That is, core 1 computes the values for $n = 1 \to 125,000$, core 2 computes the values for $n = 125,001 \to 250,000$, and so forth.

Comment: You don't get it. Not all algorithms can be parallized. No you can't do what you said, see my answer.

Comment: @reruns:  YOUR method cannot be parallelized, but *MATHEMATICA*'s can.  It uses a different algorithm from yours.  As proof:  *Mathematica* computes the (single) 100000th RamanujanTau value in $0.000168$ seconds.

Comment: Thus my question : parallelizing what ? And *"my"* algorithm **can** be parallelized in some way.

Comment: @reuns:  I'll edit my answer to address your question.

Comment: $\tau(n)$ is multiplicative and fulfills $\tau(p^{k+2}) - \tau(p) \tau(p^k) + p\,\tau(p^k) = 0$ so it is easy to compute $\tau(10^6)$ in a few ms. Of course the algorithm concern us, I downvote because you are answering a problem you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This function appears on the [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/1/12/1/a/), which is the L-function and Modular Form Database. On the linked page at the bottom, you should see a possibility of downloading the first 999999 coefficients.

It happens to be that you could also compute these in sage online for free (look up CoCalc for a free notebook), or use something like pari (free, a bit hard to use) or maple/mathematica/magma (expensive, relatively easy to use) to compute these quickly without actually programming anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function) $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\tau(n)q^n=q\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^n)^{24}$$  it is easy to generate $\tau(n),n\in 1 \ldots N$

```
% Matlab code O(N^2) operations
N = 10^6;
tau = zeros(1,N);
tau(1) = 1;
for n= 1:N
  for k = 1:24
    tau(n+1:N) = tau(n+1:N) - tau(1:N-n);
  end
end
```

---

Otherwise we can compute the coefficients of $\zeta(s)\zeta(s+3)$ and $\zeta(s)\zeta(s+5)$ ie. of [$E_4,E_6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Identities_involving_Eisenstein_series) in $\mathcal{O}(N \log N)$ operations and use the FFT convolution and [$1728 \Delta = E_4^3 - E_6^2$](http://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/1/12/1/a/) to compute $\tau(n),n\in 1 \ldots N$ in $\mathcal{O}(N \log N)$, very close to the optimal algorithm.

---

To compute an isolated value of $\tau(m)$, we might use the multiplicativity and $\tau(p^{k+2}) - \tau(p) \tau(p^k) + p\,\tau(p^k) = 0$, but say if $m$ is prime this will be useless and we'll need to compute $\tau(n)$ for $n \le m$.